# How can I convert anonymous type to strong type in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, .net-3.5

I have an array of ListViewItems ( `ListViewItem[]` ), where I store a `SalesOrderMaster` object in each ListViewItem.Tag for later reference.

I have some code that right now, goes through each `ListViewItem` safely casts the .Tag property into a SalesOrderMaster object, then adds that object to a collection of SalesOrders, only after checking to make sure the order doesn't already exist in that collection.

The process to **compare** sales orders is expensive, and I would like to convert this to a LINQ expression for clarity and performance. ( I also have the [Parallel Extensions to .NET Framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=348F73FD-593D-4B3C-B055-694C50D2B0F3&displaylang=en) installed so I can use that to further improve LINQ performance)

So without further ado: This is what I have, and then what I want. ( what I want won't compile, so I know I am doing something wrong, but I hope it illustrates the point )

What I have: ( Slow )

```
foreach (ListViewItem item in e.Argument as ListViewItem[])
            {
                SalesOrderMaster order = item.Tag as SalesOrderMaster;
                if ( order == null )
                {
                    return;
                }
                if (!All_SalesOrders.Contains(order))
                {
                    All_SalesOrders.Add(order);
                }
            }
```

What I want: ( Theory )

```
    List<SalesOrderMaster> orders = 
(from item in (e.Argument as ListViewItem[]).AsParallel() 
select new { ((SalesOrderMaster)item.Tag) }).Distinct();
```

EDIT: I know the cast is cheap, I said the "Compare", which in this case translates to the .Contains(order) operation

EDIT: Everyone's answer was awesome! I wish I could mark more than one answer, but in the end I have to pick one.

EDIT : This is what I ended up with:

```
List<SalesOrderMaster> orders = 
(from item in (e.Argument as ListViewItem[]) select (SalesOrderMaster) item.Tag).GroupBy(item => item.Number).Select(x => x.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I see nobody has addressed your need to convert an anonymous type to a named type explicitly, so here goes... By using "`select new { }`" you are creating an anonymous type, but you don't need to. You can write your query like this:

```
List<SalesOrderMaster> orders = 
    (from item in (e.Argument as ListViewItem[]).AsParallel() 
    select (SalesOrderMaster)item.Tag)
    .Distinct()
    .ToList();
```

Notice that the query selects `(SalesOrderMaster)item.Tag` without `new { }`, so it doesn't create an anonymous type. Also note I added `ToList()` since you want a `List<SalesOrderMaster>`.

This solves your anonymous type problem. However, I agree with Mark and Guffa that using a parallel query here isn't you best option. To use `HashSet<SalesOrderMaster>` as Guffa suggested, you can do this:

```
IEnumerable<SalesOrderMaster> query = 
    from item in (ListViewItem[])e.Argument
    select (SalesOrderMaster)item.Tag;

HashSet<SalesOrderMaster> orders = new HashSet<SalesOrderMaster>(query);
```

(I avoided using `var` so the returned types are clear in the examples.)

Comment: @[Lucas] But how can we select multiple fields using this method? Is there any alternative to using an anonymous type?

Comment: Ah, nevermind, got it. select new Person(e.First_name, e.Last_name)).ToList<Person>()

Answer (score 3):

The part in that code that is expensive is calling the `Contains` method on the list. As it's an O(n) operation it gets slower the more objects you add to the list.

Just use a `HashSet<SalesOrderMaster>` for the objects instead of a `List<SalesOrderMaster>`. The `Contains` method of the `HashSet` is an O(1) operation, so your loop will be an O(n) operation instead of an O(n*n) operation.

Comment: But adding items to a hash set is an O(n) operation every O(log n) adds, so you get O(n*log n)

Comment: Yes, adding items to a hash set is an O(n) operation sometimes, but so is adding items to a list, so the relative result is about the same.

Comment: So to be clear, adding the item takes about the same time for both, it's determining whether it already contains the item which is much faster in HashSet. Is that it?

Answer (score 3):

Like Marc Gravell said, you shouldn't access the `Tag` property from different threads, and the cast is quite cheap, so you have:

```
var items = (e.Argument as ListViewItem[]).Select(x=>x.Tag)
         .OfType<SalesOrderMaster>().ToList();
```

but then, you want to find distinct items - here you can try using `AsParallel`:

```
var orders = items.AsParallel().Distinct();
```