# LINQ - Having trouble getting List of IDs from a List of ObjectModel

Tags: c#, linq

I'm new to LINQ and I've been poking around the Internet and going through tutorials all day.  I have some code I thought would work but it's complaining about the return type.  Here is my code:

```
// The orgs parameter is a list of all buildings in the entire organization
// I want to retrieve only the IDs of all buildings in a particular region
private IList<int> GetRegionBuildingIDs(int regionId, List<OrgModel> orgs)
{
    var ids = from org in orgs
              where org.regionId == regionId
              select new { id = org.buildingId };
    return (IList<int>)ids;
}
```

This returns a list of ids but they are of **Anonymous Type** and the cast is not working.  I get a System.InvalidCastException.

The closest I've found to answering my question is still confusing to me.  [It's here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/802378/1735836).  `I tried to follow the answer but my select(org.buildingId) only offers .ToString`

So this is my latest try but it's wrong:

```
private IList<int> GetRegionBuildingIDs(int regionId, List<OrgModel> orgs)
{
    IEnumerable<int> ids = from org in orgs
              where org.regionId == regionId
              select (org.buildingId)._________;  // This should be .ToList
    return (IList<int>)ids;
}
```

Looking forward to a little help here.  Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `select new {}`, you can `select` it directly:

```
var ids = from org in orgs
          where org.regionId == regionId
          select org.buildingId;

return ids.ToList();
```

This is because `select new {}` uses an anonymous type with a single `int` member, as opposed to returning the `int` value directly.

You also cannot cast a Linq query to `List<T>` because they aren't instances of `List<T>`, but something else (a lazily-evaluated state-machine built-around the `yield return` C# language feature).

Of course, your code can be made much simpler

```
 private static IEnumerable<Int32> GetRegionBuildingIds(Int32 regionId, IEnumerable<OrgModel> orgs) {

    return orgs
        .Where( org => org.regionId == regionId )
        .Select( org => org.buildingId );
}
```

And if you feel like it, make your own extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<Int32> GetRegionBuildingIds(this IEnumerable<OrgModel> orgs, Int32 forRegionId) {

    return orgs
        .Where( org => org.regionId == regionId )
        .Select( org => org.buildingId );
}
```

Used like so:

```
IEnumerable<Orgs> orgsModel = GetFromDatabaseOrWhateverYourBackingStoreIs();
return orgsModel.GetRegionBuildingIds( forRegionId: 123 );
```

Answer (score 2):

As far as casting goes. try this:

```
// The orgs parameter is a list of all buildings in the entire organization
// I want to retrieve only the IDs of all buildings in a particular region
private IList<int> GetRegionBuildingIDs(int regionId, List<OrgModel> orgs)
{
    var ids = (from org in orgs
              where org.regionId == regionId
              select (int)org.buildingId).ToList();
    return ids;
}
```

or if the buildingId is nullable, you can try this

```
select (int)(org.buildingId ?? 0)
```

Comment: This won't compile. The parenthesised Linq statement has a type `IEnumerable<'a { Int32 id }>` which is not compatible with `IEnumerable<Int32>`.